# GeoTool CSV to Shape Conversion Error

Tags: geotools, csv

In the [Feature Tutorial Example](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html)

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
```

generates error:

> method getGeometryFactory in class
>   org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder cannot be applied to given
>   types;
>         required: org.geotools.factory.Hints
>         found: no arguments
>         reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Is this the right way?

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GeometryFactory geomFac = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
```

or

```
GeometryFactory geomFac = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(GeoTools.getDefaultHints());
```